# Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ,

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I can't find any error, but at terminal got this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j10s7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install plugin  ***babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread***

then add to .babelrc

`{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}`

http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Answer (score 0):

You have an error with ES6 [destruction syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

You need to fix your build process by add [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-destructuring/) or set target of your code as `es6`.

Comment: Thx, it's not plugin you support, i found is this:  babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.